# How can i retain my site traffic and promotions after change my hosting service

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting

Now am working with `Bigcommerce` , i am ready to move `magento` with `hosting provider` `Godaddy`. After am migrating `how can i retain my site traffic`.

> What is the basic steps to take retain Website traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips definitely will help you but not sure...

If you follow the instructions in this **[post](https://www.quicksprout.com/2014/06/02/how-to-retain-at-least-95-of-your-organic-traffic-after-a-site-redesign/)**, your site will not suffer the fate that you see in the chart above. Sure, you’ll experience a bit of fluctuation. Every site does after a redesign – it’s inevitable.

I’m convinced that a careful and intentional site redesign will allow you to sustain 95% or more of your site’s existing traffic. A big drop doesn’t have to happen. Plus, if your site redesign is rolled out successfully and your new design is better, then you’ll actually see your traffic rise.

Comment: Very usefully for retain site traffic.